# HTML Break after Second Argument on URL

Tags: php, altorouter

I have a problem, which I'm not sure what's causing this but here is my explanation.

I'm developing PHP Web Application with MVC Structure.

- app/

  - controller/
  - models/
  - views/

    - signup.html
    - signin.html
    - and so on .html
- public/

  - index.php
  - assets/

    - css
    - js

In all my html pages, the references on CSS and JS are 
`<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

`<link href="assets/css/core-layout-5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/pace.min.js></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/and so on.hs></script>`

I know that it looks weird? specially when the href should reference to: /public/assets/*, but I did so and the html break.

now I haven't got into part when I set my route to something like : url.dev/user/pramdpt, all still in single / such as url.dev/signin, url.dev/signup.

but when I do use for testing purpose, if I set the url with 2 slashes, it will break.

accessed with only 1 url : curiosity.dev/faq
[with only 1 slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWgph.jpg)

accessed with 2 url : curiosity.dev/faq/xxx 
[with double slashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDpJU.jpg)

Anyone ever faced it before? Is it has something to do with the CORS?

Comment: The only thing weird I see is that you didn't finish writing your `<script>` tags. I don't think anyone can help you with this if you don't show the php code that you think is behaving strangely. And, no, it probably has nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: I'm sorry, thanks for helping. I updated the answer with the closing <script> tags, because it was mistake that I didn't paste the script carefully

Comment: This is still not nearly enough information for anyone to help you. In the images you provided, there's no indication of what's wrong or what should be different. You say the href should be "/public/assets/..", is that the whole problem? Then you need to show how you're generating that code in php.